# jquery not working in asp.net mvc after publishing to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've built an mvc application which contains some jquery code.  When I run the app from my ide, everything works perfectly.  When I publish to the server and open the page, the jquery does not work.  I get object expected errors.

Could this be due to my file mappings?  here is a sample of my mapping in the app -

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

I published the app to iis7 successfully, but the jquery is broken.  I did publish to an application within an existing web site.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be experiencing problems with your relative path.

You can try this, which is a path from the application root:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Or this C# solution:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is either one of these solutions preferred over the other, or just use whatever one works?

Comment: Won't the second option also disable jQuery Intellisense for any JavaScript code on the page?

Comment: Well... yes, but his problem is a deployment not developement.